# jQuery cycle - Pager shows all queried posts' slides

Tags: jquery, wordpress, cycle, jquery-cycle

I made a page that loads post titles in a menu, clicking the titles loads that posts content into a div. Part of the content is a div with a jquery cycle script. So, every page has it's own slider, with it's own images and it's own pager.

Problem: The pager shows buttons for every slide on the page, even those that aren't showing. For example, I have 3 posts with a slider, post 1 has 2 images in the slider, post 2 has 3 images in the slider, and post 3 has 2 in the slider as well. The pager then shows 7 buttons, on every slider.

Before, it duplicated every time a post was clicked, so it has to do something with the while loop I'm thinking. This is my jquery

```
// Displaying content for selected category
$('ul.cats li.trigger').click(function(){
    var openMainContent = $(this).attr('rel');

    $('.the-content#'+openMainContent).show(); 
    $('.the-content').not('#'+openMainContent).hide();
    $('.img-slider').cycle('destroy');

    // Image slider
    $('.img-slider')
        .before('<div id="slider-nav" class="slider-nav">') 
        .cycle({ 
            fx:     'fade',
            timeout: 0,
            pager:  '#slider-nav'
    });
});
```

What do you think makes this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try by initializing the cycle plugin only on the new ones. Something like this(haven't tested that though):

```
// We need a way to distinguish navigation wrappers from one another, so we use a counter
var nav_count = 0;
// Displaying content for selected category
$('ul.cats li.trigger').click(function(){
    var openMainContent = $(this).attr('rel');

    $('.the-content#'+openMainContent).show(); 
    $('.the-content').not('#'+openMainContent).hide();

    // Image slider
    $('.img-slider:not(.img-slider-initialized)').each(function(){
        $(this).before('<div id="slider-nav-' + nav_count + '" class="slider-nav">') 
            .cycle({ 
                fx:     'fade',
                timeout: 0,
                pager:  '#slider-nav-' + nav_count
        }).addClass('img-slider-initialized');
        nav_count ++;
    })
});
```

Can you test that and see if it works?

Comment: Nope, it loads all buttons on the first post that has a slider (no matter which one you click first), and the others have no buttons at all. Still loads the pager class to every post though.

Comment: I've updated the code to go through each element - can you try again?

Comment: Okay, the other thing I think could be causing the issue is that we always used the same id for the navigation wrapper. I updated the code to make each wrapper have a different id, so if that was the issue, this should resolve the problem. Please try again :)

Comment: Awesome, that works perfectly right away :) Many thanks! I tried something like that as well using the openMainContent variable, but I didn't do it the right way apparantly :)

Answer (score 0):

**Just a guess:** does the `.before()` method adds the closing `</div>` tag to `id="slider-nav"`? It may cause broken html.

Comment: I was thinking of that as well, but it does close it. Aside from that,  logic tells me I should put .after('</div>') but that would close it _after_ the img-slider and that doesn't make sense.